# Create new files and folders in directory with 777 permissions

Tags: bash, filesystems, devops

I have a directory named folder, and i want to make that all new files and dirs which creates under this directory creates with 777 permissions, and i was tried to use setfacl command

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ mkdir folder
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cd folder/
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ touch file
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Jul 13 10:20 file
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ setfacl -R -m default:other:rwX .
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ setfacl -R -m other:rwX .
[vagrant@localhost folder]$
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ touch file2
[vagrant@localhost folder]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Jul 13 10:20 file
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Jul 13 10:21 file2
```

so as you can see after applying setfacl policies, the new file named file2 creates with default permissions

```
getfacl folder/
file: folder/
owner: vagrant
group: vagrant

user::rwx group::rwx other::rwx default:user::rwx default:group::rwx default:other::rwx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx

It's in effect session-wide for the user, though, not per directory.

Comment: ```[root@localhost dir]# umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx
[root@localhost dir]# touch file
[root@localhost dir]# ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 0 Jul 14 06:22 file```

Comment: anyway no permissions like 777

Comment: right, only directories get 777 with that mask. files don't automatically get set as executable, as that would pose a security risk. typically, whatever is writing the file should chmod appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, I use the following trick, I hope help you.
create a crontab on your server and add this line to crontab.

```
* * * * * chmod 777 /path/to/your/directory -R
```

Comment: thank you! but i think another solution exists )

Comment: yes you are right, always have better solution for linux issues. you can use `umask 000` command. by this way the new files that are created will have 777 permissions. read more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder)

Comment: no. with umask 000 files creates with rw but not x permissions